xr_interpolate in dea_tools.spatial how does it treat nan values in point data
I am trying to use xr_interpolate for rainfall data, but I am not clear how it is treating nan values in the observed data. They are point locations, and some days of the record don't have observed values. Could someone either let me know or point me to the right documentation section please?

The docs for the function are here: https://knowledge.dea.ga.gov.au/notebooks/Tools/gen/dea_tools.spatial/#dea_tools.spatial.xr_interpolate
There is a jupyter notebook outlining its functionality here: https://knowledge.dea.ga.gov.au/notebooks/How_to_guides/Interpolation/
And the function relies on scipy.interpolate libraries so look through that documentation to find how scipy.interpolate handles NaNs. For example: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html
Alternatively, you could fill/interpolate away the NaNs in your point data before passing it to xr_interpolate(). In (geo)pandas you can use this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html
